# How to sort Pandas DataFrame both by MultiIndex and by value?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

**Sample data:**

```
mdf = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,50],[1,2,20],
                    [1,5,10],[2,8,80],
                    [2,5,65],[2,8,10]
                   ], columns=['src','dst','n']); mdf

    src dst n
0   1   2   50
1   1   2   20
2   1   5   10
3   2   8   80
4   2   5   65
5   2   8   10
```

`groupby()` gives a two-level multi-index:

```
test = mdf.groupby(['src','dst'])['n'].agg(['sum','count']); test

        sum count
src dst 
1   2   70  2
    5   10  1
2   5   65  1
    8   90  2
```

**Question:** how to sort this DataFrame by `src` ascending and then by `sum` descending?

I'm a beginner with pandas, learned about sort_index() and sort_values(), but in this task it seems that I need both simultaneously.

**Expected result**, under each "src" sorting is determined by the "sum":

```
        sum count
src dst 
1   2   70  2
    5   10  1
2   8   90  2
    5   65  1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [29]: test.sort_values('sum', ascending=False).sort_index(level=0)
Out[29]:
         sum  count
src dst
1   2     80      2
    5     10      1
2   8     80      1
```

**UPDATE:** very similar to [@anonyXmous's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49265839/5741205):

```
In [47]: (test.reset_index()
              .sort_values(['src','sum'], ascending=[1,0])
              .set_index(['src','dst']))
Out[47]:
         sum  count
src dst
1   2     70      2
    5     10      1
2   8     90      2
    5     65      1
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution exactly demonstrates my problem: the later sort_index() overrides the previous value sorting. I updated the question with more data and expected outcome.

Suggested solution gives result exactly the same as before any sorting.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! Now I see how it works. Appreciate.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else comes across this using google as well. Since pandas version 0.23, you can pass the name of the level as an argument to `sort_values`:

```
test.sort_values(['src','sum'], ascending=[1,0])

Result:
         sum  count
src dst            
1   2     70      2
    5     10      1
2   8     90      2
    5     65      1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can reset the index then sort them by chosen columns. Hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd

mdf = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,50],[1,2,20],
                [1,5,10],[2,8,80],
                [2,5,65],[2,8,10]
               ], columns=['src','dst','n']); 
mdf = mdf.groupby(['src','dst'])['n'].agg(['sum','count']); 
mdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
mdf.sort_values(['src', 'sum'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
print(mdf)

Result:
       src dst sum  count
    0   1   2   70   2
    1   1   5   10   1
    3   2   8   90   2
    2   2   5   65   1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and drawing my attention to the `inplace` parameter and `reset_index()`. I accepted the other answer because it also restored the initial multiindex.

Comment: You can undelete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296346/run-jupyter-notebook-out-of-jupyter-environment, you just need to run the `.py` files with `ipython`, not just plain `python`.