# Run Jupyter notebook out of Jupyter environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook containing python and R scripts as well as magic commands. What I need is to schedule a task using Windows Task scheduler that somehow triggers run of this notebook. My scripts run at night and I prefer Jupyter to be closed.
So I wonder if there is a way to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to do this

Create a bat file that you can reference in the windows task scheduler.

Code as follows:

`cd C:\path to your notebook
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute NOTEBOOKTOEXECUTE.ipynb`

I needed to include the path, as the console would be run from the system path and thus unable to find the notebook.

Comment: Easiest way! Much Appreciated!

Comment: Hi I have been trying to make this bat file but its not working. The "--" isnt it means commenting out? Can you specify what to put in the batch file exactly? The help would be really appreciated.