# How to sort values in a MultiIndex pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex. I want to sort the values of a column, and compare values in index level0. If the value is the maximum, the id should be 1, and if the value is the secondary, the id should be 2. Finally, output its sorted id.

For example:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar','bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'foo','qux', 'qux'],
      ['one', 'two', 'three','one', 'two', 'one', 'two','three', 'four',  'one', 'two']]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(11), index=arrays,columns=['values'])
df
```

output:

```
            values
bar one     -1.098567
    two     -0.936011
    three   -0.654245
baz one     -0.637409
    two     -0.439939
foo one      0.238114
    two      1.146573
    three   -0.512294
    four    -0.611913
qux one     -0.481083
    two      0.515961
```

Finally, I want this:

```
            values      sort
bar one     -1.098567      3
    two     -0.936011      2
    three   -0.654245      1
baz one     -0.637409      2
    two     -0.439939      1
foo one      0.238114      2
    two      1.146573      1
    three   -0.512294      3
    four    -0.611913      4
qux one     -0.481083      2
    two      0.515961      1
```

Comment: did you mean like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264510/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-both-by-multiindex-and-by-value

Comment: As a side note, you may want to avoid naming a column `'values'`: it is already an attribute that lets you access the underlying NumPy array

Comment: You may also want to give the seed when using `np.random` so that others can easily recreate your dataframe values.

Comment: Thanks，@BradSolomon

Answer (score 1):

Group on the first level (i.e. level 0), and then [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) them in descending order.

```
>>> df.assign(sort=df.groupby(level=0).rank(ascending=False))
             values  sort
bar one   -1.098567     3
    two   -0.936011     2
    three -0.654245     1
baz one   -0.637409     2
    two   -0.439939     1
foo one    0.238113     2
    two    1.146573     1
    three -0.512295     3
    four  -0.611913     4
qux one   -0.481083     2
    two    0.515961     1
```

Comment: GREAT...but one thing is that when two values are the same, the output will be .5. Why?

Comment: There are different methods that give different behaviors.  Have a look at the documentation (I provided the link in the question).  The methods are "average" (which is the default value) along with "min", "max", "first" and "dense".